# Parcelable encoder/decoder (External class)

Tags: android, android-intent, parcelable, parcel

I have an external Java library with a lot of common objects (i.e. User with name, surname, address...). The thing that i want to build up is a (de)serializer class that transforms all my objects into Parcelable objects to send with Intents. The problem is that Android's intents don't support putExtra(String,Parcel) or something similar. Have you got an idea on how to overcome this inconvenient?
Actually I'm putting all my instances in the Application class, but I think it's a dirty method...cleaner one?

Comment: Create a model class and put all your relevant data in it and make it parcelable. On a note string by default is serializable take a look at the android String class

Comment: I just have a Json (de)serializer, but is it efficient? I like to have always clean solutions...
The problem is that I receive those objects over JSon so i have
User user = json.decode(string);
Now i want to parcel it
ParcelableUser puser = (ParcelableUser) user;
But now I cannot use this casting because of Java restrictions over subclass casting.

Comment: u make this User class parcelable, in Android that is so called as a clean solution

Answer (score 2):

You can use [putExtras(Bundle extras)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtras%28android.os.Bundle%29) method of Intent and implement in your class method `exportToBundle()` which returns [Bundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) with values of this object. If you don't want to create any other methods in your class you can create another utility class with static method which converts object of your class to Bundle. And if your class is `Parcelable` you can put it directly to the Bundle using `putParcelable(String key, Parcelable value)` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly put a Parcelable class into the intent so what you're looking for is supported.  There is a word of warning here and I think you've already have this concept down by mentioning serialize / de-serialize.  You are sending a copy of the class which will be reconstructed by the class processing the intent.  [The official android example is weak because only one integer is sent and we can do that already.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html)

Example intent passing a class

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, TheClassImCalling.class);
            // use a constant that's public or an R string so both the sender
            // and receiver are working on the same class
            // the class you are sending goes into the putExtra method statement.
    intent.putExtra(ImageTextListViewActivity.EXTRA_KMLSUMMARY,
    mKmlSummary);
    startActivity(intent);
```

You pull a copy out of the class out with a statement like this using the same constant you used to send it.

```
KMLSummary mkmlSummary = intent.getExtras().getParcelable(
                ImageTextListViewActivity.EXTRA_KMLSUMMARY);
```

Here are the methods that have to be implemented

```
public class KmlSummary implements Parcelable {
```

// a constructor with Parcel as argument.
   // you read and write the values in the same order.

```
public KmlSummary(Parcel in) {
    this._id = in.readInt();
    this._description = in.readString();
    this._name = in.readString();
    this.set_bounds(in.readDouble(), in.readDouble(), in.readDouble(),
            in.readDouble());
    this._resrawid = in.readInt();
    this._resdrawableid = in.readInt();
    this._pathstring = in.readString();
    String s = in.readString();
    this.set_isThumbCreated(Boolean.parseBoolean(s));
}


// Overridden methods for the Parseable interface.
@Override
 public void writeToParcel(Parcel arg0, int arg1) {
    arg0.writeInt(this._id);
    arg0.writeString(this._description);
    arg0.writeString(this._name);
     arg0.writeDouble(this.get_bounds().southwest.latitude);
    arg0.writeDouble(this.get_bounds().southwest.longitude);
     arg0.writeDouble(this.get_bounds().northeast.latitude);
    arg0.writeDouble(this.get_bounds().northeast.longitude);
     arg0.writeInt(this._resrawid);
    arg0.writeInt(this._resdrawableid);
     arg0.writeString(this.get_pathstring());
    String s = Boolean.toString(this.isThumbCreated());
     arg0.writeString(s);
 }

@Override
 public int describeContents() {
    //
     return 0;
 }


    // Some glue to tell the OS how to create the class from the parcel
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
     public KmlSummary createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new KmlSummary(in);
     }

    public KmlSummary[] newArray(int size) {
         return new KmlSummary[size];
    }
};
}
```

That's it you can serialize the class into an intent and de-serialize the class from the intent.

Good Luck
Danny117